# Elasticsearch | Mapping exclude field with bulk API

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I am using bulk api to create index and store data fields. Also I want to set mapping to exclude a field "field1" from the source. I know this can be done using "create Index API" reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html but I am using bulk API. below is sample API call:

POST _bulk

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", _type = 'testType', "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

Is there a way to add mapping settings while bulk indexing similar to below code:

```
  { "index" : { "_index" : "test", _type = 'testType', "_id" : "1" },
     "mappings": {
          "_source": {
               "excludes": [
                             "field1"
                           ]
          }
     }
  }
  { "field1" : "value1" }
```

how to do mapping with bulk API?

Answer (score 1):

It is [not possible](https://qbox.io/blog/understanding-bulk-indexing-in-elasticsearch/) to define the mapping for a new Index while using the bulk API. You have to create your index beforehand and define the mapping then, or you  have to define an index template and use a name for your index in your bulk request that triggers that template.

The following example code can be executed via the Dev Tools windows in Kibana:

```
PUT /_index_template/mytemplate
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "te*"
  ],
  "priority": 1,
  "template": {
    "mappings": {
      "_source": {
        "excludes": [
          "testexclude"
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "testfield": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "testfield" : "value1", "defaultField" : "asdf", "testexclude": "this shouldn't be in source" }

GET /test/_mapping
```

You can see by the response that in this example the mapping template was used for the new **test** index because the **testfield** has only the keyword type and the source excludes is used from the template.

```
{
  "test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "_source" : {
        "excludes" : [
          "testexclude"
        ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "defaultField" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "testexclude" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "testfield" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also the document is not returned with the excluded field:

```
GET /test/_doc/1
```

Response:

```
{
  "_index" : "test",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "defaultField" : "asdf",
    "testfield" : "value1"
  }
}
```

Hope this answers your question and solves your use-case.

Comment: I tried your solution but got an error.

Solution I applied using Elasticsearch 7.7. Any idea what is this error?

PUT _template/template_manoj
{  "index_patterns": ["manoj-*"],  
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "excludes": [
                  "@message"
                ]
    }
  }
}

{ "index" : { "_index" : "manoj-2021-10-26", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "testfield" : "value1", "@message": "this shouldn't be in source" }

Comment: Error:
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "{\"statusCode\":200,\"responseBody\":{\"took\":312,\"errors\":true}}",
    "stack": [
        "Error: {\"statusCode\":200,\"responseBody\":{\"took\":312,\"errors\":true}}",
        "    at _homogeneousError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:12:12)",
        "    at postError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:29:54)",
        "    at done (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:58:7)",
        "    at fail (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:70:7)",

Comment: "    at Object.fail (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:106:16)",
        "    at /var/task/index.js:43:25",
        "    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:187:13)",
        "    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)",
        "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)"
    ]
}

Comment: Hi i ran these examples via the dev tools window in Kibana. In what environment (elasticsearch client) are you trying to create that template? Looks to me like node environment, i have no experience with that, you have to check how you create a put requests that sends that template to Elasticsearch in that client environment. I added the information that the example code is kibana Dev Tools specific to the answer.

Comment: Hi I am using Kibana dev tool for template 
PUT _template/template_manoj { "index_patterns": ["manoj-*"], "mappings": { "_source": { "excludes": [ "@message" ] } } }

Comment: And, Using aws cloudwatch to forward the logs and elasticsearch lambda function for sending the bulk request to create index. Getting error below in cloudwatch:
 
"reason": "Can't merge because of conflicts: [Cannot update excludes setting for [_source]]"